# Using autolayout in a tableview cell that should properly resize on iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa, autolayout

I have a tableview cell with two labels (see screenshot 1). Both those labels have numberOfLines 2.
Both labels have a left, top and right margin constraint. The view also has the "Apply resizing views constraints thing" set for siblings and ancestors as well as descendants. (See screenshot 2)

Basically everything works as it should except for the labels height. The XIB is designed with the iPhones width. If I but text into the label which is too long for the iPhones screen but is presented on the iPad where one line is still enough, it starts making the label too big. (See Screenshot 3)

Is there a setting I missed?
I was already playing with content hugging and compression resistance priorities and the intrinsic content size popup in IB... Nothing changed anything...

Do I need to make the layouting myself in `layoutSubviews:`? Or is there a way to to it with autolayout in IB?

Screenshot 1:
[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2:
[image: Screenshot 2]

Screenshot 3:
[image: Screenshot 3]

**EDIT:**

This hack would solve my problem... But it's a hack and I don't like hacks

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //TODO: this is a HACK
    [self performSelector:@selector(foo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}


- (void)foo
{
    [self.titleLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.subTitleLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

Comment: You don't have a constraint in there tying the lower label to the bottom of the cell content view do you?

Comment: I don't want it to be pinned to the bottom... Both labels should be just enough height to fit it's content

Comment: Yep, just checking that you didn't since those screenshots look like the second label might be pinned down

Comment: oh.. ok.. but it's not pinned down... and the same error is happening to the top label as well

Answer (score 0):

The magic property's constraint for UILabel :  `Greater Than or Equal` for `Height Constraint`

[image]

With that the label is autoresizing to display multi-line.

[image]
[image]

Hope that will help.

Comment: Did you set a constraint between the second label and the bottom of the cell ? if yes remove it or at least put it `Greater Than or Equal` to 5 or 10.

Comment: I missunderstand maybe.. Do you want that your labels have the same heigth ?

Comment: Nope, I want them to fit it's content. So if one line would be enough, the label height should only be one line.
Obviously the calculation of the needed height is done with the intrinsic content size of the XIB (which is iPhone), not the actual cell's width in the iPad

Comment: Do you have a sample project with it working? Cause setting the height to be >= doesn't help me. And I also think it's that the autolayouting is done when the cell is still in it's XIBs width... Which is wrong...